# Socialization gem, getting posts from users I follow doesn't works

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I want to get list of users's post, which I follow.
In conrtoller I write:

```
@posts = Post.where(id: current_user.followers(User).map(&:id));
```

In view (I use haml):

```
- @posts.each do |post|
  = render partial: 'users/post', locals: { post: post, user: @user}
```

`_post.html.haml`:

```
.post-title
  %img.img-rounded.post-image{:src => "#{@user.avatar.url}"}/
  %h4.post-name
    = @user.first_name + ' ' + @user.last_name
  .post-date= post.created_at.strftime('%d %b - %k:%M')
.post-content
```

I followed 2 users, which have posts, but I see nothing at all. And how to add current_user's posts to all post?

**UPD**
ActiveRecord generated SQL queries in the console

```
<Post id: 1, title: "First dream", content: "This dream about nothing", visible: false, date: "2015-06-18 09:37:00", created_at: "2015-06-18 09:38:17", updated_at: "2015-06-18 09:38:17", user_id: 1>
```

Comment: What does `@posts` contain? Can you execute it in a console and show us the generated SQL query?

Comment: @Pablo, I add query above

Comment: On your SQL query, it says `visible: false`. that might be the reason why you don't see anything? if not, could you post your errors?

Answer (score 0):

I think it should not be :
@posts = Post.where(id: current_user.followers(User).map(&:id));

but
@posts = Post.where(id: current_user.followees(User).map(&:id));

From the docs :
What items are you following (given that an Item model is followed)?
user.followees(Item)